# dead letter queue not getting message after retry completed

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

After retry limit reached message is not pushed to DLQ. Also my message in main queue is also removed getting empty logs after retry done. But retry is happening for the specified limit. After retry nothing is happening. Also tried by throwing AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException  from consumer  but till  facing  same issue. DLQ not receving any message. After retry message not routed to DLQ

```
    @Bean
    Queue testMsgDLQ() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(testDLQ).build();
    }


    @Bean
    DirectExchange testMsgDLX() {
        return new DirectExchange(testDLX);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding testDLBinding(Queue testMsgDLQ,DirectExchange testMsgDLX) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(testMsgDLQ)
                .to(testMsgDLX).with(testDLQ);
    }
    @Bean
    Queue testMsgQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(testQueue)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", testDLX)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key",testDLQ).build();
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange testMsgExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(testExchange);
    }


    @Bean
    Binding testMessageQueue(Queue testMsgQueue,DirectExchange testMsgExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(testMsgQueue)
                .to(testMsgExchange).with(testQueue);
    }

**>Configuration**
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setHost(host);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setAddresses(address);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setUri(url);
/*        cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherConfirmType(CachingConnectionFactory.ConfirmType.CORRELATED);*/
        cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheMode(CachingConnectionFactory.CacheMode.CONNECTION);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setRequestedHeartBeat(10);

        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrentConsumers);
       factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        factory.setAdviceChain(RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
                .maxAttempts(5)
                .backOffOptions(2000, 2.0, 10000) // initialInterval, multiplier, maxInterval

                .build());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory publisherConnectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(publisherConnectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(final RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
    }

**>Consumer**
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory="rabbitListenerContainerFactory", queues = "${rabbitmq.email.queue.name}")
    public void receiveMessage(MessageKeyVo messageId) {

        System.out.println("Demo");

        throw new RuntimeException("q");

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what is wrong with your code, but the feature works well:

[image]

Here is Spring Boot code I used to test against my locally running RabbitMQ.

In the `application.properties` I just have this:

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true
```

To enable retry on a listener container with 3 attempts and `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` as a default policy. See `AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` for more information.

The code looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So76100648Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So76100648Application.class, args);
    }

    private final String testDLQ = "testDLQ";

    private final String testDLX = "testDLX";

    private final String testQueue = "testQueue";

    private final String testExchange = "testExchange";

    @Bean
    Queue testMsgDLQ() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(testDLQ).build();
    }


    @Bean
    DirectExchange testMsgDLX() {
        return new DirectExchange(testDLX);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding testDLBinding(Queue testMsgDLQ, DirectExchange testMsgDLX) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(testMsgDLQ)
                .to(testMsgDLX).with(testDLQ);
    }

    @Bean
    Queue testMsgQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(testQueue)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", testDLX)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", testDLQ).build();
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange testMsgExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(testExchange);
    }


    @Bean
    Binding testMessageQueue(Queue testMsgQueue, DirectExchange testMsgExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(testMsgQueue)
                .to(testMsgExchange).with(testQueue);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = testQueue)
    public void testListener(Object payload) {
        throw new RuntimeException("intentional");
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return args -> rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(testExchange, testQueue, "test data");
    }

}
```

So, I have exactly the same AMQP objects like in your code and then I have a `@RabbitListener` which just throws an exception on message receipt.

In logs after sending ad receiving message I have:

```
2023-04-25T09:36:55.827-04:00  WARN 12456 --- [ntContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Retry Policy Exhausted
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: null
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.example.so76100648.So76100648Application.testListener(java.lang.Object)' threw exception
```

So, everything confirms that we are OK.

Please, share with us a simple minimal project to reproduce.

Comment: updated the question with full bean config and consumer

Comment: Yes, you have exactly the same code as me. Please, check with RabbitMQ broker if your `testQueue` has that `x-dead-letter-exchange`. I don't see anything else how we can help here.

Comment: In broker while creating/config queue we need to add any additional params

Comment: No, if you have permissions to create those object on the broker via `RabbitAdmin`, then everything is OK from a code perspective. It is not clear if you use Spring Boot though, since you have configured everything manually, so probably you just don't have a `RabbitAdmin` bean which would scan for those RabbitMQ objects to create on connection establishment.

Comment: Why am not getting any exception after retry is completed.recoverer not throwing anything

Comment: It is not clear: the code is OK. Without any simple project to reproduce it is hard to localize what is wrong.

Comment: Would be also great if you can debug your solution and see where it goes after your exception in the `@RabbitListener` method.

Comment: It working now my code doesnt have rabit mq admin user access .We granted admin acess it fine now.

Comment: Is there any way to print or log business exception trace. Because am not seeing any messages related to any business exception occured

Comment: So, it was not a Spring Boot app then. Please, consider to chose tags for your questions here on SO wisely next time. Not sure what you talk about business errors: perhaps that deserves a new SO question?